# Column value from first df to another df based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have original df where I have column "average", where is average value counted for country . Now I have new_df, where I want to add these df average values based on country.

```
df
id country   value  average
1   USA      3      2
2   UK       5      5
3   France   2      2
4   USA      1      2

new df
country   average
USA       2
Italy     Nan
```

I had a solution that worked but there is a problem, when there is in new_df a country for which I have not count the average yet. In that case I want to fill just nan.

Can you please recommend me any  solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need add `average` column to df2 use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df2.merge(df1.drop_duplicates('country')[['country','average']], on='country', how='left')
```

If need aggregate `mean`:

```
df2.join(df1.groupby('country')['average'].mean(), on='country')
```